# Craft Migration fails (SuperTable propagationMethod)

Tags: plugin-supertable, upgrades

I'm trying to upgrade Craft from 3.3.1.1 and I'm getting an error. I am updating via Composer and get the following error when I run the migration script after upgrading:

```
Unknown Property: Setting unknown property: verbb\supertable\fields\SuperTableField::propagationMethod

Migration: craft\migrations\m190913_152146_update_preview_targets
```

I received a similar error when I tried to run the save entries script from the CLI as recommended in the upgrade documentation.

`- Resaving test (10554) ... error: Setting unknown property: verbb\supertable\fields\SuperTableField::propagationMethod`

I'm running the upgrade on my local server via Valet. Restoring the database brings me back to the migration screen...

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: If there is a better place to direct this question, please let me know. At the moment I’m dead in the water on this update attempt...

Answer (score 1):

On the chance that anyone is having this same issue, here is what I needed to do to fix the issue (based on help provided by Craft's Support -- many thanks to them):

The Super Table plugin was out of date. The admin panel didn't show the issue and a composer update didn't either. I had to manually update the composer.json file to reflect the current Super Table version, `"verbb/super-table": "2.4.9"`. Then I was able to clear the composer cache and run an update. The migration then worked just fine.